# Getting error "The Type or Namespace name 'DBAccess;" cannot be found

Tags: c#

For my class "WindowsFormsApp1", I'm running into a problem which occurs when trying to access my "DBAccess" class.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Signin : Form
    {
        DBAccess objDbAccess = new DBAccess(); //where error occurs 
        DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();
```

even when i try to add "using DBAccess;" I run into an error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace DatabaseProject
    {
        class DBAccess
        {
            private static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            private static SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            private static SqlDataReader DbReader;
            private static SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            public SqlTransaction DbTran;

            private static string strConnString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SocialNetwork;Integrated Security=True";
```

Could someone help me understand what i'm doing wrong here? I've been fiddling with this for a while trying to find out and cant seem to get it.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but one of the things you are doing wrong is making all of those SqlXXX objects static. Don't do that! Declare them as close to where you need them and Dispose them as soon as you don't. Do not make them static! It also doesn't make sense to declare an instance and then only reference static properties. That's no good either

Comment: And the answer to your problem is that you've declared your class in a child namespace. So as scoped and based on your currently imported using statements, it's really a `DatabaseProject.DBAccess`

Comment: i'm very new to C# and am somewhat of a bad programmer. Could you point me to some resources on this specific topic?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add using WindowsFormsApp1.DatabaseProject; to SignIn class

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using WindowsFormsApp1.DatabaseProject;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Signin : Form
    {
        // ......
    }
}
```

And replace

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace DatabaseProject
    {
        class DBAccess
        // .......
    }
```

with

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1.DatabaseProject
{
   public class DBAccess
   {
       // ....
   }
}
```